# Mapping names to codes contained in lists of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame in the following format:

```
id      date       item
1 2015-02-01     [0, 2]
2 2015-08-01  [1, 5, 2]
3 2015-07-01  [1, 8, 3]
4 2015-09-01  [8, 1, 0]
```

I need to map the item numbers to product name available from the following data frame:

```
item  product
0      ducky
1  chocolate
2        dog
3      light
4        toy
5       rope
6       shoe
7      shirt
8      table
9         tv
```

The final data frame should look like this:

```
id      date                       item
1 2015-02-01               [ducky, dog]
2 2015-08-01     [chocolate, rope, dog]
3 2015-07-01  [chocolate, table, light]
4 2015-09-01  [table, chocolate, ducky]
```

I have tried doing this with a series of .groupby(), unstacking, restacking, pivoting, etc. I am looking for a more practical (elegant) way of doing it in just a few lines of code. 
Here's some code for data replication. Much appreciated.

```
orders = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2015-02-01','2015-08-01','2015-07-01','2015-09-01']),
    'item': [[0, 2], [1, 5, 2], [1, 8, 3], [8, 1, 0]]
}
)

items = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'item': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'product': ['ducky','chocolate','dog','light','toy','rope','shoe','shirt','table','tv']
}
)
```

Comment: Here's an ugly solution: orders['item'] = orders['item'].apply(lambda x: [items[items['item'] == k]['product'].values[0] for k in x])

Comment: @rmilletich hey, it works and it's certainly a one liner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this, assuming items ordered with the index (otherwise, you can set the index as the item code):

```
orders['item'] = [[items.loc[k,'product'] for k in i] for i in orders.item]
```